# HTML code appearing in CSV FILE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, csv

We want to create a CSV file from data .It is showing HTML tags .Same working fine for xlx file.
Below is code.

```
     Dim response As System.Web.HttpResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
        response.Clear()
        response.ClearHeaders()
        response.Write("<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=UTF-8""/>")

        'Chose what type of file needed ie.e CSV /XLS
        If _exportType = ExportTypeEnum.CSV Then
            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
        Else
            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
        End If

        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & FileNameToExport)
        Dim sw As System.IO.StringWriter = New StringWriter()

        Dim htw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        Dim dg As DataGrid = New DataGrid()
        Dim dv1 As DataView = data 
        dg.DataSource = dv1
        dg.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        dg.DataBind()
        dg.RenderControl(htw)
        response.Write(sw.ToString())
        response.End()
```

Please suggest WHY it is not working for CSV file , although it is fine for xls file.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain what "it is not working" means.  Meanwhile, look at where you are setting the `response.ContentType`  both paths of that `if` statement do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly writing the output in HTML format.  Notice this line:

```
response.Write("<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=UTF-8""/>")
```

And notice the object you're using to write output:

```
Dim htw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
```

This is all emitting HTML to the output.  It "works fine" for an Excel file because Excel understands HTML structures when rendering a file.  CSV, however, is a much "flatter" format and only knows plain text (delimited by a comma).  You'll also see the HTML tags if, for example, you use this code to write to a `.txt` file.

If you want a CSV file without HTML, you shouldn't write HTML content to it.

Comment: Yes, You are right. But can you please suggest alternative of it ?